# Can I use the .net serial port class with .NET Framework 1.1?

Tags: .net, winapi, serial-port

Required to write a serial communication C++ program in Visual Studio C++ 2003 with the .NET Framework 1.1

Also, can not use open source libraries, only windows supported libraries.

I noticed there is no documentation for framework 1.1 here and it states
`Note: This class is new in the .NET Framework version 2.0.` :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Out of luck using this class?

Is there a [better method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx)?

Comment: How about using a framework that isn't ten years old?

Comment: `I cannot use open source libraries` ... That's a very stupid restriction.  What makes you think you can re-invent the wheel better than they did?

Comment: @SLaks I see a _requirement_.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Requirements can also be stupid.

Comment: You'll need to go Win32 I'm afraid. There are open source libraries, but since you can't use them you'll have to write the wrappers yourself. Not terribly hard, but tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately the SerialPort class is not available in .NET 1.1.  Developers working with .NET 1.1 or earlier still need to use the MSComm control.  However, I would definitely ask whether it can be written using .NET 2 or later.  Every Windows operating system that supported .NET 1.1 also supports .NET 2, and should already have it installed in most cases.

References:
MsComm control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259393(vs.60).aspx
SerialPort not available: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/